# Increment a counter inside a byte array

Tags: java, byte, bit

I have an array of 5 bytes (fixed length). First 21 bits represent a counter and the rest 19 some id. I need to increment the counter by one. How do I do that?

Comment: Currently, we have to guess a bit about the detailed bit/byte layout. Does `array[0]` hold the most significant counter bits (bits 20...13)? In `array[3]`, do the upper 5 bits represent the remaining 5 counter bits? That would be a plausible layout, but I've seen the strangest things happen...

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff the most significant bit of the counter is the 21-st bit.  So the array[2] holds it.

Comment: Hopefully, in array[2] it's the lower 5 bits holding the msb counter bits 16..20.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the memory layout as I understand it from the OP's comments:

```
array[0]: bits 0..7 are counter bits 0..7 (lsb)
array[1]: bits 0..7 are counter bits 8..15
array[2]: bits 0..4 are counter bits 16..20 (msb)
          bits 5..7 are part of the id
array[3]: bits 0..7 are part of the id
array[3]: bits 0..7 are part of the id
```

Then

```
int byte0 = (int) array[0] & 0xff;
int byte1 = (int) array[1] & 0xff;
int byte2 = (int) array[2] & 0x1f;

int count = byte0 | (byte1 << 8) | (byte2 << 16);

count = (count+1) & 0x1fffff;

array[0] = (byte) (count & 0x0000ff);
array[1] = (byte) ((count & 0x00ff00) >> 8);
array[2] = (array[2] & 0xe0) | (byte) ((count & 0x1f0000) >> 16);
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I solved your problem. Since the memory layout is not described in detail, I assumed a layout. You can obtain the counter, increase it by 1, and then set the counter. If the layout is as desired, it needs to be fully tested. I'm not dealing with data overflow situations, and you may need to add some restrictions.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[5];
        bytes[2] = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 0x1fffff; i++) {
            setCount(bytes, i);
            if (getCount(bytes) != i) {
                System.out.println(i);
                debug(bytes);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getCount(byte[] bytes) {
        return ((bytes[2] >> 3) & 0x1f) + ((bytes[1] << 5) & 0x1fff) + ((bytes[0] << 13) & 0x1fffff);
    }

    public static void setCount(byte[] bytes, int count) {
        bytes[0] = (byte) (count >> 13 & 0xff);
        bytes[1] = (byte) (count >> 5 & 0xff);
        bytes[2] = (byte) ((bytes[2] & 0x7) + ((count & 0x1f) << 3));
    }

    public static void debug(byte[] bytes) {
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.print(b >> i & 1);
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Count:" + getCount(bytes));
    }

    public static void printInt(int num) {
        for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(num >> i & 1);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes MSB to be in array[0], but according to OP's comments, it's in array[2].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I solved your problem.

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //################
        //#  BIG ENDIAN  #
        //################
        
        //initial counter == 1 (b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1)
        //initial ids == 3 (b000_0000_0000_0000_0011)
        byte[] array = { 0, 0, 8, 0, 3 };
        int counter = ((array[0] & 0xFF) << 13)
            | ((array[1] & 0xFF) << 5)
            | ((array[2] & 0xF8) >> 3);
        System.out.println(counter); //1
        ++counter;
        System.out.println(counter); //2
        //Repack the counter into the array.
        array[0] = (byte)((counter & 0x1FE000) >> 13);
        array[1] = (byte)((counter & 0x1FE0) >> 5);
        array[2] = (byte)(((counter & 0x1F) << 3)| (array[2] & 0x7));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); //[0, 0, 16, 0, 3]
        //Retry & Verify
        counter = ((array[0] & 0xFF) << 13) //Same as above. Nothing is changed.
            | ((array[1] & 0xFF) << 5)
            | ((array[2] & 0xF8) >> 3);
        System.out.println(counter); //2
        ++counter;
        System.out.println(counter); //3
        
        //###################
        //#  LITTLE ENDIAN  #
        //###################
        
        //initial ids == 3 (b0000_0000_0000_0000_011)
        //initial counter == 1 (b0_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001)
        byte[] arr = { 0, 0, 96, 0, 1 };
        counter = ((arr[2] & 0x1F) << 16)
            | ((arr[3] & 0xFF) << 8)
            | (arr[4] & 0xFF);
        System.out.println(counter); //1
        ++counter;
        System.out.println(counter); //2
        //Repack the counter into the array.
        arr[2] = (byte)((arr[2] & 0xE0)  | ((counter & 0x1F0000) >> 16));
        arr[3] = (byte)((counter & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        arr[4] = (byte)(counter & 0xFF);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); //[0, 0, 96, 0, 2]
        //Retry & Verify
        counter = ((arr[2] & 0x1F) << 16) //Same as above. Nothing is changed.
            | ((arr[3] & 0xFF) << 8)
            | (arr[4] & 0xFF);
        System.out.println(counter); //2
        ++counter;
        System.out.println(counter); //3
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This assumes MSB to be in array[0], but according to OP's comments, it's in array[2].

Comment: @Ralf Kleberhoff Oh really? If so I'll update my answer later.